# Undefined citations in Natbib (ShareLaTeX)

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, natbib, sharelatex

All of my citations are undefined in a ShareLaTeX document. A minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{natbib}

\bibliographystyle{natbib}
\begin{document}

\section{Some section}
    \citet{LAS13}
    \citet{LCN09}


\bibliography{bib}

\end{document}
```

And bib.bib contains this:

```
    @Article{LCN09,
      Title                    = {Title},
      Author                   = {Author1 and Author2},
      Journal                  = {Journal},
      Year                     = {2009},

      Owner                    = {Owner},
      Timestamp                = {2015.06.01}
    }

@Article{LAS13,
  Title                    = {Title2},
  Author                   = {Author and Author and Author},
  Year                     = {2013},

  Owner                    = {Owner},
  Timestamp                = {2015.05.18}
}
```

I've tried clearing the cache-files, compiling twice in LaTeX first, but I don't know why it's still not working.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: The instruction `\bibliographystyle{natbib}` is almost certainly an error. `natbib` is a citation management package that comes with several bibliography styles (e.g., `plainnat` and `unsrtnat`), but it shouldn't occur in the argument of `\bibliographystyle`.

Comment: @Mico Should we consider this as a typo, hence closing as off-topic?

Comment: @Johannes_B - Well, now that Werner has posted an answer, in which `unsrtnat` is mentioned as a possible bibliography style, it's probably better not to close the posting.

Comment: @Mico Agreed. :-)

Comment: I wish I could accept your comment answer Mico, but I'll accept the one I got so others might benefit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should choose one of the available bibliography citation styles; `natbib` is not such a style:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

\section{Some section}
\citet{LAS13}
\citet{LCN09}

\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\bibliography{main}

\end{document}
```

Here is a basic [`natbib`](http://ctan.org/pkg/natbib) [template in ShareLaTeX](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/bibliographies/natbib) that you can follow.